# I get String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error on some strings that worked for previous rows

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have an odd issue. I know that this is a common error and is easily fixed by using proper use of DateTime.ParseExact with a correct format. I have a database that have column for date formatted as yyyyMMdd. I am using following code to convert to DateTime variable:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
date = DateTime.ParseExact(row[2].ToString().Trim(), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This code is looping through each row. It works fine until it hits one location where it just keeps throwing this error. I am not sure what is so different about it. I checked through the value and it is "20040414". few rows before this one also had the same value but they worked without issue. What could be the issue?

Exception:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format,
>   DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi)

Comment: Do you get the exception on last row?

Comment: Yes. I updated the post.

Comment: I think it's very unlikely that it was *actually* the same value. I suspect there might be something like non-visible whitespace there. I suggest you log both the (trimmed) string  and its length just before you try to parse it. (As an aside, why are you creating a default `DateTime` value? Why not just have `DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(...)`?

Comment: I also tried the following, but i got the same error: `string dateToParse = new string(row[2].ToString().Trim().Where(c =>char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());`

Comment: Is AllowUserToAddRows = true?

Comment: I was also logging the output values of each rows and they were actual string.

Comment: Where would i be using AllowUserToAddRows? I am not creating or modifying  table, just reading off the table.

Comment: @JonSkeet Let me try your suggestion of using DateTime.ParseExact at initialization

Comment: Well that won't fix the problem, but it's cleaner code...

Comment: I see. I also tried to get the ObjectType to see if something is change in my program, but they are still correct. Is it possible some how the culture is the problem?

Comment: I also tried: `string dateString = DateTime.ParseExact(row[2].ToString().Trim(),"yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
       
        cashAppliedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,"MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`

Comment: Something very odd just happened. I changed my code as such `string dateString = DateTime.ParseExact(row[2].ToString().Trim(),"yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        oDate = (object)dateString;`
and I still got the same error at this last line about String not recognizing as a valid datetime'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your issue, but you could try and use TryParse instead of ParseExact. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e(v=vs.110).aspx May be able to help you find your issue

```
DateTime date = new DateTime;
if(DateTime.TryParse(row[2].ToString().Trim(), out date))
{
//successful datetime put into date
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and same result.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will do anything, but to guarantee the value is a string and exactly what u expect, you could set a temp variable equal to the row[2] value then try and make the datetime using the temp string variable...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
date = Convert.ToDateTime(row[2].ToString().Trim()).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

I am not sure,as I haven't tested.hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. This code will not work since the output is a string that  you are applying back to a DateTime. Even I perform another convert over the result, it will still error.

Comment: String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", row[2].ToString().Trim()); ,Please try,this should work,as its working for me.

Comment: I get again the following message: `System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)`